# Any problems with UCC (multidomain) SSL certs on iOS and Windows Phones?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, ios

Are they any known issues with UCC (multidomain) SSL certs on iOS or Windows Phone?

Let's say I want to have Exchange server under `outlook.mycompany.com` and RemoteApp Portal under `portal.mycompany.com`.

So cert will be look like:

```
mycompany.com (primary domain)
outlook.mycompany.com (additional name)
portal.mycompany.com (additional name)
```

Will iOS or WP complain on my SSL cert because of fact Exchange server name is given as additional name in cert?

Answer (score 2):

After checking on real world example, answer is NO: iOS and WP are NOT complaining on additional name in SSL certs. They act as correct certs. Tested with GoDaddy certs.